# How to mount an exFAT external hardrive? Using ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, mount, hard-drive, exfat

I tried the following situation and I'm getting a bunch of errors:

https://raycodingdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/mounting-exfat-filesystem-in-ubuntu/

I'M ALSO using ubuntu version 11.10. Everytime I try to upgrade to a new version my old computer no longer works. So I want to make this work first on my version to back all my files up.

Do I need a higher version?

Someone posted this solution:

> Ubuntu 14.04 or higher
>
> Since Ubuntu 13.10, this package is in the main repository. Just
>   install exfat-fuse and exfat-utils:
>
> `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` [Ubuntu 12.04]
>
> For ubuntu 13.04 and lower, you'll need a ppa to install the exfat
>   support. Installation procedure:
>
> `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat`
>
> If you see the error gpg:
>   "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping during the
>   apt-add-repository step, then you'll need to manually install the
>   signing key and run the apt-get update and apt-get install steps after
>   that:
>
> `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4DF9B28CA252A784`

Comment: Are you really running Ubuntu 11.10?  The link you followed is quite old, but the correct answer will depend upon knowing what version of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 has been past EOL for several years.  Please install a supported version (14.04, 16.04, 17.04, or 17.10).  Note that 17.04 will be EOL in just a couple months, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 has not been supported since mid 2012 - you will need to update.  Have you tried running any of the more current versions from a liveUSB?  I read that an upgrade process will not work at this point, and that you would need to do a fresh install.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for the prompt response. I'm live now. Yes I am running that version. As you said it seems I need to do a fresh install. The reason I want the external HDD (exfat format) to be read is so that I can back up all my files and also transfer over an old encrypted ubuntu external drive (can only be read on ubuntu). Before trying any upgraded version. There has to be a way for me to mount my exFat without doing a fresh install. What do you think?

Comment: I meant "live" in that I'm waiting for your response :)

Comment: Ubuntu 11 was before my time, I'm afraid, and getting repos to work for it may not be possible.  Can you reformat your external drive to ext4?

Comment: I have sensitive data already on the hardrive. Data that was copied from an old drive that was damaged and I luckily was able to transfer over all of that data. I would try this as a last measure. But I want to see if it is at all possible first. I'm sure there's a key package or ppa command I can put to download the repos and pkg for the mount to be possible.

Comment: any suggestions for where I could look or someone to ask?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, perhaps @videonauth knows?  If you don't have way too much data, and a fairly solid internet connection perhaps you could copy data from your computer to a google drive?  Or beg/borrow/buy a second external drive?

Comment: Let's see what @videonauth says. Otherwise will ext4 format work 100% on ubuntu 11.10 ?

Comment: What is the root file system in your Ubuntu 11.10 (is it `ext3` or `ext4`)? You can use the same file system on the external drive as what you use as the root file system (mounted on '/'). You can check with `sudo lsblk -f`

Comment: @sudodus I get "not a block device" error

Comment: should I be doing anything else

Comment: Please describe exactly what you do in what operating system, when you get  "not a block device" error . Do you run exactly this command: `sudo lsblk -f` when you are running Ubuntu 11.10? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: Yes im running in terminal on ubuntu 11.10. I actually received this when re-running the command: FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT

Comment: sr0 sda sda1 (ext 4) sda 2 sda5 swap   @sudodus

Comment: Best way to approach this is making yourself an USB live stick from which you boot from, you can install exfat there while running (tho this change is not permanent) and move your files from that computer to your USB drive you want to use as backup solution. IMHO installing an ppa or even trying to update 11.10 is a futile attempt when it is deleted later anyways, so safe yourself some time and headache.

Comment: I concur with @Videonauth's approach. As a minor variation, you can set up a live system with persistence or install Ubuntu to a USB drive. Both would keep all changes including the installation of exFAT drivers across reboots.

Comment: @DavidFoerster question 1: will I be able to access my old HDD even with a USB drive version of ubuntu. In that I thought the usb stick limited you to only accessing the USB's storage? question 2: Are you saying that once I install the exFat on the newer USB version it will make the changes on my old 11.10 version of ubuntu when I reboot without the USB stick?

Comment: If you install ExFAT on the USB it is on the USB and does not make changes to the installed system, but youre able to access the old systems files and (giving that you have two USB ports) aloows you to move the files over every Ubuntu Live is in fact a fully working OS, just on a stick. Just choose the 'Try Ubuntu' option instead of ''Install'. If it comes to which version, i'd suggest putting 16.04 on that stick, it is very stable in the newer builds of that ISO image.

Comment: perfect, I will try it out and let you know if it works. @Videonauth does exFat come automatically on the ubuntu 16.04 or do I need to run the sudo commands for downloading the exfat pkgs as well?

Comment: If you not have persistence on that stick you might need to install it every time you boot that stick up I think, not sure right now if the live image comes with exFAT support already installed. But here on the site are already [couple of questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+create+usb+persistence+) about how to make an USB with persistence which have excellent answers. As well you can have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://www.pendrivelinux.com/ for viable options and tutorials.

Comment: @Videonauth thank you, creating the flash drive as we speak. Let's see if I can make the transfer of files and install the exfat pkgs

Comment: I would say find me in [chat] but you're sadly not yet have the reputation needed for that. So simply ping me here.

Comment: yeah I saw that, that's too bad. i'm currently running off the usb stick. Wow the system crashed on me twice and everytime i try to open a new application the screen goes fuzzy. So far i was able to keep it stable for 2 secs to run a commend. let's hope this work. Do you think it's because my computer ram and requirements or the usb stick itself are not powerful enough to run 16.04?@Videonauth

Comment: What system do you have there?

Comment: @Videonauth it's an old HP laptop. So far looks like ubuntu is running ok to be able to run terminal. I am now connected to my router directly. However I am running the sudo commands for exfat and still get same error as I was before the bootable usb. does this have anything to do with mkusb link you provided me. I don't understand what that link is for? This is the error i'm getting when running "sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils

Comment: Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package... etc.... Unable to locate package exfat-fuse.... etc.... has no installtion candidate  @Videonauth

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69471/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-halve-how-to-mount-an-exfat-external-hardrive).

Comment: also when trying to mount it directly says error mounting ...unknown filesystem type